# Loop through JSON data with unspecific index key

Tags: arrays, json

I have this json file below and I want to be able to loop through and print the corresponding value. e.g If I send a params "en", I should be able to print Unjha.

```
[
    {
       "apmc_code":1000,
       "en":"Unjha",
       "mr":"उंझा",
       "hi":"उंझा",
       "pa":"ਉਂਝਾ",
       "gu":"ઊંઝા",
       "te":"ఉంఝా",
       "kn":"ಉಂಜಾ",
       "ta":"உன்ஜா",
       "ml":"ഉൻഝാ"
    },
    {
       "apmc_code":1001,
       "en":"Jamnagar",
       "mr":"जामनगर",
       "hi":"जामनगर",
       "pa":"ਜਾਮਨਗਰ",
       "gu":"જામનગર",
       "te":"జామ్‌నగర్",
       "kn":"ಜಾಮ್‌ನಗರ",
       "ta":"ஜாம்நகர்",
       "ml":"ജാംനഗർ"
    },
 ]
```

Any help?

Comment: But what about Jamnagar?

Comment: Yes, I just use the first one as an example. I need to be able to select the value of any of the keys

Answer (score 0):

```
iterate over outer-list
    iterate over item-map
        print map.key = map.value
```